# Google Analytics Segments Recording Data Before Implementation

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, utm

On Tuesday 23rd, for the first time ever, I made a segment with the following details:

Medium - Exactly Matches - "email"
Source - Exactly Matches - "account_information"

I, made a URL (using Google URL Builder tool) which includes these as UTM parameters: https://www.website.com/?utm_source=account_information&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=privacy_notice_update

I have never sent out a link to users with UTM parameters before, and it seems reasonable unlikely that someone would have ever made a custom URL themselves with the parameters.

I am the only person who has tested this link.

When I look at my analytics using my new segment I can see that:
- Thursday 18th Oct had 1 User
- Friday 19th Oct had 1 User
- Monday 22nd Oct had 1 User

How is it possible that there are users popping up before the date I even made the segment or created the link?

Thanks :)

Comment: what's the condition of the segment that you've created?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dalmto, when I searched for the best stack exchange site I chose this as it had quite a few google analytics questions..

Comment: @XTOTHEL can you elaborate? I posted the condition in the original post (exactly matches etc), or are you talking about something else?